# How to access FaceID for new iPhone X?

Tags: ios, iphone-x

iPhone X is coming out with introduced FaceID to unlock phone and make Apple Pay.

Can we access the API?

I know last time we have to wait until TouchID release to developer.

Is there any dateline when perhaps?

Comment: You just use the same APIs that you use for TouchID to request a biometric verification.  On a iPhone X it will use Face ID, on other devices it will use TouchID

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually already available in Xcode 9 in the same place TouchID functionality is found.  [Look at LocalAuthentication -> LAContext -> `LABiometryType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/2867583-biometrytype) for example.

If you look at the documentation at a higher level, [`LAContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext), the new API's can be currently found with a "Beta" label on them (presumably these will be removed as soon as Xcode 9 & iOS 11 are officially released).

Comment: Are you able to get this to work on an actual device? On the simulator, it works fine for me. But on a device with iOS 11, I get: -[LAContext biometryType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Comment: look at the below "answer" @r3c0d3 (it should be a comment):  "Xcode 9.1 beta (9B37) has working support for Face ID."

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more clear with my question. I do see Face ID working well in the simulator for Xcode 9.1 beta (9B37). However, if I build on an iOS 11.0 device that only has TouchID, calling LAContext().biometryType says it's an unrecognized selector. I want to use the biometryType to present a different UI for the different biometric capabilities.

Comment: Update: LAContext().biometryType works well on iOS 11.0.3. I am using the  macro of `if #available(iOS 11.0.3, *)` to make sure it is not called on earlier versions.

Comment: Using Xcode 9.1 beta 2, I just tested on 11.0.2 with an iPhone 7 Plus (real device) and the biometryType call works fine. So maybe the issue is only on 11.0 and 11.0.1? Can we even download a simulator running 11.0?

Comment: The unrecognized selector issue may be specific to the iOS 11 beta. I only see the crash logs from beta 5.

Comment: The unrecognized selector issue is specific to ios 11.0.0 only I have added a check in my below answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are a comment and an answer here that each tell only part of the story, so let’s bring them together:

---

As noted [by @Paulw11 in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231683/how-to-access-faceid-for-new-iphone-x#comment79426809_46231683), the APIs for authenticating with Touch ID — [`LAContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext) [`canEvaluatePolicy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514149-canevaluatepolicy) to check for availability, [`evaluatePolicy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514176-evaluatepolicy) to actually request authentication — work just the same for Face ID. You might notice that all of those APIs never actually mention Touch ID, just “biometrics” in the abstract... it’s almost as if Apple was thinking ahead when they released that API back in iOS 8.

Apple’s Craig Federighi confirmed this in [a recent appearance on The Talk Show podcast](https://daringfireball.net/thetalkshow/2017/09/15/ep-200). He says that he and other Apple employees carrying iPhone X have been running existing apps — bank apps, airline apps, etc — that use these APIs, and they “just work” with Face ID. The same API call just automatically invokes the new UI, except it’s usually faster because the user is probably already looking at the phone so they don’t have to do anything.

---

Now, as [@MichaelDautermann’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46231721/957768) notes, there are also new APIs for distinguishing Touch ID from Face ID: [`LAContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext) [`biometryType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/2867583-biometrytype) tells you which kind of biometrics the current device supports.

If the same APIs work for invoking both Touch ID and Face ID, why also the new thing? It’s so your app can talk about it in your UI. Think about all the bank and credit card and password manager and whatnot apps you’ve ever used — you log in to that app with a password, then afterward it asks you if you want to use Touch ID instead of your password next time. All of that is custom UI from those apps’ developers, so they’ll need to use this new API so their UI can correctly say “use Touch ID” or “use Face ID” depending on the current device.

Comment: Um...this doesn't seem to work (at least with the simulator). If I enroll EITHER TouchID or FaceID in the sim, it is as if nothing is happening. Is there a trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 9.0.1 and 9.1 beta (9B37) have working support for Face ID.

APIs did not work in Xcode 9.0 GM.

AND, there is a bug that affects iOS 11.0.0 (the very first public version of iOS 11) which will cause the `biometryType` function to crash. Therefore, you must use this check:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0.1, *) {...}
```

AND, Apple changed the `LABiometryType enum` names in Xcode 9.2.

Comment: I’ve provided this as an answer because the question is about when is the API available. The answer is “yes, you can access the API now that Apple has fixed it in Xcode 9.1, and just yesterday in 9.0.1”. The selected answer suggests that the API is working in Xcode 9.0. It does not work. I know this from first hand experience and a post In the Apple discussion boards. Having a broken API that does nothing is fairly useless.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

```
enum BioType {
case kFace
case kTouch
case kNone
}

func checkForBiometry() -> BioType {
    let context = LAContext()

               if #available(iOS 11.0, *),context.responds(to: #selector(getter: LAContext.biometryType))  {
            if context.biometryType == .typeFaceID {

                return .kFace
        }
        return .kTouch
    }
    return .kNone
 }
}
```

Edit:

Added     `responds(to: #selector)` check as the app crashes with `-[LAContext biometryType]: unrecognized selector` on iOS 11.0.0 only devices.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that there's a bug in the simulator for Xcode 9.

If I use Xcode 9.1 beta, [This code](https://bitbucket.org/bmltios/na-meeting-list-administrator/src/783231e9354fa6733e3b0710444fe7b47a33ee47/NA%20Meeting%20List%20Administrator/View%20Controllers/InitialViewController.swift?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#InitialViewController.swift-499) works:

```
let authenticationContext = LAContext()
var error: NSError? = nil

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    if authenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        let bioType = authenticationContext.biometryType
        if bioType == .typeFaceID {
            touchIDButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"FaceIDLogo"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            touchIDButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"FaceIDLogo-Highlight"), for: UIControlState.highlighted)
        }
    }
}
```

I should note that it's important to run [LAContext.canEvaluatePolicy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514149-canevaluatepolicy) before checking the biometric type.

Comment: Do note that in the just released Xcode 9.2 beta, with iOS 11.2, the `LABiometryType` enum values have changed to `faceID` and `touchID`.